# How to properly remove for all users preinstalled Windows 10 applications?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-10

I would like to properly remove for current and future users the toy applications not required for work Microsoft preinstalled : Candy Crush
My problem is I either nuke everything and we don't even have weather/Microsoft store left, or new users gets all the productivity annihilators again.

How do I properly remove for all users a Microsoft preinstalled application ?
Preferably with a method not requiring more than Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

A powershell example for an app;

`get-appxpackage *bingfinance* | remove-appxpackage`

You can try windows store for business too if you can, to give control over the store

Comment: Note that `remove-appxpackage` only removes apps from the current user. Any other users that log in will still get the packages installed from provisionedpackages.

Answer (score 0):

`Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage` and 'Remove-AppxPackage' are the PowerShell cmdlets. You can also remove from the WIM or from an installed image with `dism /remove-provisionedappxpackage /packagename:"example-package.1.2.3.4"`